# Red Hat disk utility only works for root, no sudoer?

Tags: rhel, privileges

I need to format a hard drive in Red Hat 6.4. When I use the graphical "Disk Utility" provided by Red Hat, it asks to authenticate using the root password. On this machine I am a sudoer and do not have the root password. Is there a way to run the disk utility as a sudoer?

Comment: How are you starting disk utility, through the GUI or from the terminal like: `sudo system-config-lvm`?

Comment: @Jesse_b I am just starting it from the "System" menu on the desktop

Comment: If you start it with `sudo system-config-lvm` does it still ask for the root password?

Comment: @Jesse_b system-config-lvm is not a recognized command. This is Red Hat 6.4

Comment: Which disk utility are you using?  The gnome utility or redhat's `parted`?  I don't think I've ever used redhat with a gui outside of the class but I think it installs the gnome gui.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was the following:

1. Right click on the "Applications / System Tools / Disk Utility" menu choice
2. Select "Add this launcher to desktop"
3. Right click on the resulting desktop icon and pick "Properties"
4. In the resulting properties dialog box it revealed the utility to be launched by the command "palimpsest"
5. Open a terminal and type "sudo palimpsest"

This opened the disk utility with super user rights and I had no further problems.